# Set blog archive to active when browsing archive

Tags: menus

I have a link to my blog archive in my main menu. When the user clicks it and the blog is displayed (on /blog/ - I have a static front-page) the link receives the "current" class (or whatever the name is). When the user clicks on a blog post the blog link in the menu *still* has the "current" class (or current-page-parent or similar).

This is all good. *However*, when the user clicks on one of the blog **categories** the blog link no longer has the "current" class (or any of the parent classes - IE it's impossible to style it as selected).

This is not only true for the normal blog archive but also for any custom post type archives with custom taxonomies.

What I would like is that the blog link still has the active class. Even when browsing blog categories, tags or perhaps even dates.

Is there any non-hackish way of solving this?

Comment: How is your main menu generated? Is it a `wp_nav_menu` instance?

Comment: It's a Custom Menu Widget

Comment: You could potentially look at the wp_nav_menu_item_classes filter (it's called something like that!) and then use the is_archive() conditional (as well as get_option("page_for_posts")) to draw it all together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so this is how I ended up solving it. Please note it's not exactly super tested but it *seems* to work at least. Also, if you're *not* using a static front-page it may require some changes (get_option('page_for_posts') notably).

Also note that I'm using "active-parent" as my class name. This is because I'm also using Roots' menu cleanup code which replaces all the "current_page"-classes with "active", "active-parent" and "active-ancestor". You might wanna use the "official" WP-class names instead.

```
<?php
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'sleek_active_archive_link_on_taxonomies', 10, 2);

function sleek_active_archive_link_on_taxonomies ($cssClasses, $item) {
    global $wp_query;

    # Only do this on archive pages
    if (is_archive()) {
        # This is the link to the blog archive
        if ($item->object_id == get_option('page_for_posts')) {
            # If we're on a blog archive - give the blog link the active class
            if (is_category() or is_tag() or is_day() or is_month() or is_year()) {
                $cssClasses[] = 'active-parent';
            }
        }
        # This is a link to a custom post type archive
        elseif ($item->type == 'post_type_archive') {
            # If we're on a taxonomy and this post type has that taxonomy - make it look active
            if (is_tax()) {
                global $wp_taxonomies;

                $term = $wp_query->get_queried_object();

                if (isset($wp_taxonomies[$term->taxonomy])) {
                    if (in_array($item->object, $wp_taxonomies[$term->taxonomy]->object_type)) {
                        $cssClasses[] = 'active-parent';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $cssClasses;
}
?>
```